# How should I save to the database?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created a Customer model in Django and am not able to save the data to the database table and when I click the signup button it just redirects me back to the home page.
I have attached below the customer model and the signup function.
...please help me resolve the issue.
customer.py

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def register(self):
        self.save()
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
    else:
        postData=request.POST
        first_name=postData.get('firstname')
        last_name=postData.get('lastname')
        phone=postData.get('phone')
        email=postData.get('email')
        password=postData.get('password')
        print(first_name,last_name,phone,email,password)
        customer=Customer(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,phone=phone,email=email,password=password)
        customer.register()
        return HttpResponse("Signup success")
```

signup.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="p-4 m-4">
        <div class="col-lg-5 mx-auto border rounded pt-4">
            <h3 class="alert alert-light border rounded" >Create An Account</h3>
            <form action="/" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <!--firstname-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Mike">
                    
                </div>


                  <!--lastname-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Ross">
                    
                </div>

                  <!--phone-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Phone No</label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="9876543210">
                    
                </div>

                <!--email-->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="abc@gmail.com">
                  
                </div>
                
                <!--password-->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="********">
                    
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I hope the URL of this sign up page corresponds to the value of the action attribute you put on the form?

Comment: i have saved it like this ........from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, signup
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('signup', signup),
]

Answer (score 0):

Try this change

Model

```
def register(self):
     return self.save()
```

Comment: Nope, still not saving.

Comment: It was not showing errors before also, just not saving it...I tried your code and the result was still the same.

Comment: Please let me see your url for the sign up page

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, signup
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('signup', signup),
]

Comment: You see, you're not posting to the right address. You're posting to index and it can't process the data

Comment: Action attribute should be '/signup'